# Vue Js Toggle Tree Like Cascading Dropdown

Tags: javascript, rest, vue.js, axios

I have a issue about toggle[ like this.][1]

When i click on each plus, api generate child data from parent. Like a cascade dropdown, but i want to toggle all with a button.

When i try it, my toggle just open two levels, not affect every level.

I dont know why this happens.

Let me explain how the toggle button should work:

When i click a expand button, all first/parent elements send a request to my api. Im watching "firstdata parameter" inside a component request, sending to api, then all data comes from my api and filling related variables.

Then i have second state variable for trigging child/sub levels.

I'm set next level status variable to true when the request is done. Next component inside watch this variable for requests but this is not working properly.

Im sorry for bad english i hope i could tell my problem

Thanks

First Level Codes

```js
watch:{
      toggleAll:{
        handler(toggler){
          console.log("trigger Stations");
          this.getStations().then(resp =>{
            if(toggler==true)
            {
              console.log(toggler);
              this.$store.commit('Vehicle/setToggleAllGroup',true)
            }
          });

        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      getStatus(status) {
        return parseStatus(status)
      },
      async getStations(){
        if(this.toggled){
          this.toggled = false
          return;
        }
        await this.$store.dispatch('Vehicle/getCounts', {type: 'status', param: this.status._id})
        this.toggled = true
      },
    }
```

```html
<v-row>
      <!--<td > <v-checkbox v-if="level>2"/></td>-->
      <v-col md="2">
        <v-btn style="background-color: darkcyan;"  class="white--text" x-small @click="getStations">
          <v-icon v-if="!toggled">mdi-plus</v-icon>
          <v-icon v-else>mdi-minus</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
        {{ getStatus(status._id) }}
      </v-col>
      <v-col md="1"></v-col>
      <v-col md="1"></v-col>
      <v-col md="1"></v-col>
      <v-col md="1"></v-col>
      <v-col md="1"></v-col>
      <v-col md="1"></v-col>
      <v-col md="1"></v-col>
      <v-col md="1"></v-col>
      <v-col md="1" class="text-success font-weight-bold">{{ status.count }}</v-col>
      <v-col md="1">{{ ((100 * status.count) / totalVehicleAmount).toFixed(2) }}</v-col>
      <v-col md="12" v-if="toggled && stations.statuses[status._id].stations.length && stations.statuses[status._id].name==status._id  ">
        <all-vehicles-by-status-station-row   :key="station._id.code" v-for="station in stations.statuses[status._id].stations" :station="station" :status="status"/>

      </v-col>
    </v-row>
```

Station Codes

```js
 watch:{
      ToggleAllGroup:{
        handler(){
          console.log("trigger Group");
          this.getGroup()
        }

      }
    },
    
       async getGroup() {
        if (this.toggled) {
          this.toggled = false
          return;
        }
        await this.$store.dispatch('Vehicle/getCounts', {
          type: 'station',
          param: this.status._id,
          station: this.station._id.code
        })
        this.toggled = true
      },

    }
```

```html
<v-row>
    <v-col md="2" class="pl-10">
      <v-btn style="background-color: darkcyan;" class="white--text"  x-small @click="getGroup">
        <v-icon v-if="!toggled">mdi-plus</v-icon>
        <v-icon v-else>mdi-minus</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      {{ station._id.code }}
    </v-col>
    <v-col md="1"></v-col>
    <v-col md="1"></v-col>
    <v-col md="1"></v-col>
    <v-col md="1"></v-col>
    <v-col md="1"></v-col>
    <v-col md="1"></v-col>
    <v-col md="1"></v-col>
    <v-col md="1"></v-col>
    <v-col md="1">{{ station.count }}</v-col>
    <v-col md="1">{{ ((100 * station.count) / totalVehicleAmount).toFixed(2) }}</v-col>
    <v-col md="12" v-if="toggled && groups.stations[station._id.code].groups.length &&  groups.stations[station._id.code].name==station._id.code">
      <all-vehicles-by-status-group-row    v-for="group in groups.stations[station._id.code].groups" :key="guid(group._id.group)" :group="group" :status="status" :station="station" />

    </v-col>
  </v-row>
```

Station Codes

When i click toggle all  first getStations Watch working properly but station inside getGroups Watch not trigging properly ..
this work just partwhere

for example

> X --> First Main Category
> X1  ->Sub Category
> X1.2 ->SubtoSub Category
>
> Y  --> Second Main Category
> Y1 --> Sub Category  (Works)
> -------- this data doesnt come because watcher doesnt trigging.

Comment: Could you possible create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) demonstrating your problem? It would be much easier to debug that way.

Comment: unfortunately i cant share some  codes .